# How to write multiple different dataframes to a single sheet in excel row by row

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have two dataframes

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('src_lnd.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('lnd_pst.csv')
```

Their outputs are
df1:

| Source | Landing | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 120 | 120 | Pass |

df2:

| Landing | Persistence | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 120 | 120 | Pass |

I need to write both these dataframes to an excel file such that it looks like
Excel file:

| Source | Landing | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 120 | 120 | Three |

| Landing | Persistence | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 120 | 120 | Three |

So literally just write the dataframes as is row by row.
I will also have more dataframes created in the future which I will have to append to the same in a new row. All the data is in one sheet only

Comment: Why does the result column change to three?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the columns for each dataframe as a row and concat the two dataframes together.

```
# set column names as first row and concat dataframes
final_df = pd.concat([df1.T.reset_index().T, df2.T.reset_index().T], axis=0)
```

This outputs:

| 0 | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Source | Landing | Result |
| 120 | 120 | Pass |
| Landing | Persistence | Result |
| 120 | 120 | Pass |

And you can rename the columns to something more suitable before writing it into the file.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need them to be two separate tables.